# TypeError: iteration over non-sequence... in python

Tags: python

here is the code, its supposed to read from a file and then produce a dictionary...

```
def get_songs(setlists):
    f = file(setlists)
    d = {}
    next_line = f.readline()
    while (next_line != ""):
        if next_line[0].isdigit():
            concert1 = concert(int(next_line.split("-")[0]) , int(next_line.split("-")[1]) , \
                                       int(next_line.split("-")[2]) , next_line.split("-")[3].strip("\n"))
            for i in f.readline().split('/'):
                d[i.strip(" ").strip("\n").split("(")[0]] = (concert1 if not d.has_key(i.strip(" ").strip("\n").split("(")[0])
                                                            else ([d[i.strip(" ").strip("\n").split("(")[0]] , concert1] if
                                                                  isinstance(d[i.strip(" ").strip("\n").split("(")[0]] , concert)
                                                                  else d[i.strip(" ").strip("\n").split("(")[0]] + [concert1]))
        next_line = f.readline()      
    return d
```

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: you should at least rewrite your program to avoid doing the same thing multiple times ie: `next_line.split("-")` can be done once and assigned to variable

Comment: This code is full of stuff that looks off, you should use `open()` not `file()`, and use a `for` loop over the file instead of `file.readline()` and `with`.

Comment: @Lattyware `file()` may be OP's own function :)

Comment: Please consider reading the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html). A big part of using Python is to write readable code (though of course that is not the only reason to use Python).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where the error is. One thing I could notice in the code is that after the `for i in ...` code, the d[..] takes either a single value or an array:

```
d[..] = (concert1 
    if cond1 else 
    ([d[..], concert1] if cond2
        else d[..]+concert1)
```

I'd avoid putting such expressions inline and do an if/else like:

```
tmp = None
if cond1:
  tmp = concert1
elif cond2:
  tmp = [d[d[i.strip(" ").strip("\n").split("(")[0]] , concert1]
else:
  tmp = d[i.strip(" ").strip("\n").split("(")[0]] + [concert1]


d[i.strip(" ").strip("\n").split("(")[0]] = tmp
```

I can see that the last `else` is somewhat incorrect (?) str + array will be a str imho?

As a sidenote, instead of all those strip/trim you may want to use a regexp...